Moderator Pro Tem Announcement
Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:
  
We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.
Did I overlook anyone?
Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in no way a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why you'll have your elections in several weeks.
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.
Edit: Ninefingers and Thomas Pornin have asked to step down. We are very grateful to both of them for all the time and effort they put in as moderators.
Mikeazo and Hendrik Brummermann have graciously stepped up to take over the spots. Welcome to the team!
 

Just wanted to (ab)use the option to answer to say that they do a great job. Thanks guys! 

^^ What he said
